# Character encoding for Thai characters

Tags: encoding, internationalization, rtf

I have a requirement to read a RTF file with Thai characters and write it to a text file. I tried using TIS-620, MS874, ISO-8859-11, but Thai characters are not displaying properly when I open the resulting output file in notepad or textpad. But it works well with Wordpad. Please guide me.

Comment: No the output file is text file.
We solved the issue with the code posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Code that solved the problem (posted in comment, adding here to make it readable!):

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);
//creating a default blank styled document
DefaultStyledDocument styledDoc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
//Creating a RTF Editor kit
RTFEditorKit rtfKit = new RTFEditorKit();
//Populating the contents in the blank styled document
rtfKit.read(din,styledDoc,0);
// Getting the root document
Document doc = styledDoc.getDefaultRootElement().getDocument();
//Printing out the contents of the RTF document as plain text
System.out.println(doc.getText(0,doc.getLength()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think notepad handles all character encodings, from a little Googling. Could you try re-encoding the characters into UTF-8 (or some other unicode format), since Notepad does handle that correctly? You'll [want to use the BOM](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx).

I also stumbled across a [tool for converting files in Thai](http://www.lyndonhill.com/Projects/thaiconv.html) into various other encodings.

Finally, is there a requirement that the files can be opened in Notepad? It's not as if Notepad is the last word in text editing.

Comment: FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
 DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);
 //creating a default blank styled document
 DefaultStyledDocument styledDoc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
 //Creating a RTF Editor kit
 RTFEditorKit rtfKit = new RTFEditorKit();
//Populating the contents in the blank styled document
 rtfKit.read(din,styledDoc,0);
 // Getting the root document
 Document doc = styledDoc.getDefaultRootElement().getDocument();
 //Printing out the contents of the RTF document as plain text
 System.out.println(doc.getText(0,doc.getLength()));

Comment: How did that solve the problem? That doesn't do anything with encodings of the file output stream at all!